# Click event listener stop working after transcription from HTML to Rails 4 with React

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, onclicklistener

**Can you help me to make click event listener detailed below to work in Rails4/React?**

Consider the following HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>WebSite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.source.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
</head>

<body class="with-side-menu wet-aspalt-theme">
    <header class="site-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="hamburger hamburger--htla">
                    <span>menu</span>
                </button>
            <div class="site-header-content">
                <div class="site-header-content-in">
                    <!--.site-header-shown-->
                    <div class="mobile-menu-right-overlay"></div>
                    <div class="site-header-collapsed">
                        <div class="site-header-collapsed-in">
                        </div>
                        <!--.site-header-collapsed-in-->
                    </div>
                    <!--.site-header-collapsed-->
                </div>
                <!--site-header-content-in-->
            </div>
            <!--.site-header-content-->
        </div>
        <!--.container-fluid-->
    </header>
    <!--.site-header-->

    <div class="mobile-menu-left-overlay"></div>
    <nav class="side-menu">
        <header class="side-menu-title mt-md">
            Menu
        </header>
        <ul class="side-menu-list">
            <li class="grey">
                <a href="#"> <span class="lbl">
                       Item1</span> </a>
            </li>
            <li class="grey opened">
                <a href="#"> <span class="lbl">
                       Item2</span> </a>
            </li>
            <li class="grey">
                <a href="#"> <span class="lbl"> Item3</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="grey">
                <a href="#"> <span class="lbl"> Item4</span> </a>
            </li>
            <li class="grey">
                <a href="#"> <span class="lbl"> Item5</span> </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--.side-menu-->
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="container-fluid">

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--.page-content-->
    <script src="js/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also consider the following function from the app.js file

```js
 // Left mobile menu
 $('.hamburger').click(function(){
  if ($('body').hasClass('menu-left-opened')) {
   $(this).removeClass('is-active');
   $('body').removeClass('menu-left-opened');
   $('html').css('overflow','auto');
  } else {
   $(this).addClass('is-active');
   $('body').addClass('menu-left-opened');
   $('html').css('overflow','hidden');
  }
 });
```

When I open the html above, with all the dependencies and toggle device toolbar on Chrome inspector, the event listener for the button with the class="hamburger hamburger--htla" appears on the event listeners tab, and the side menu hide/show behavior works perfectly.

The problem happens when the same code is ported to Rails 4 with React. The event simply disappears, though the hide/show left menu behavior doesn't work.

Here is the Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.7.1'
# Use SASS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'pagarme'
# gem for sending variables to JS
gem 'gon'
gem 'react-rails-img'
gem 'react-rails'
gem 'cancancan'
gem 'devise', '4.1.0'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'pg'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'sendgrid'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'validates_cpf_cnpj'
gem 'cloudinary'
gem 'attachinary'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'jwt'
gem 'react-rails-hot-loader'
```

Here is the application.js

```js
//= require jquery/dist/jquery
//= require tether/dist/js/tether
//= require bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap
//= require toastr/toastr
//= require cloudinary
//= require bar-graph
//= require echarts
//= require turbolinks
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require react_rails_img
//= require components
//= require_tree .
```

Here is the related React code:

```
class Header extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            response: []
        };

    }
    componentDidMount() {
        return $.get({
            url: '/auth/is_signed_in.json',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: (function(_this) {
                return function(data) {
                    return _this.setState({response: data});
                };
            })(this)
        });
    }
    render() {
        let menu;
        if (this.state.response.signed_in) {
            menu = [
                React.createElement(NotificationWindow, {key: 1}),
                React.createElement(UserMenu, {key: 2})
            ];
        } else {
            menu = [React.createElement(NavbarLoginLink, {key: 1})];
        }
        return (
            <header className="site-header">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <a className="site-logo" href="#">
                        <img className="hidden-md-down" alt src="/assets/logo-tw-w-md.png"/>
                        <img className="hidden-lg-up" alt src="/assets/sign-tw-w-md.png"/>
                    </a>
                    <button className="hamburger hamburger--htla">
                        <span>menu</span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="site-header-content">
                        <div className="site-header-content-in">
                            <div className="site-header-shown">

                                <button type="button" className="burger-right">
                                    <i className="font-icon-menu-addl"/>
                                </button>
                                {menu}
                            </div>
                        </div >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header >
        );
    }
}
```

And the erb code that loads the references:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta content="" name="description">
        <meta content="" name="author">
        <title>website</title>
        <%= Gon::Base.render_data %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag controller.controller_name, media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <% if Rails.env.development? %>
          <%= javascript_include_tag "application/development_dependencies" %>
        <% end %>
        <%= cloudinary_js_config %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body class="with-side-menu wet-aspalt-theme">
        <%= react_component 'Layout' %>
        <%= yield(:side_bar) %>
        <div class="wrapper">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Layout.js.jsx

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            React.createElement(Header)
        );
    }
}
```

**Can you help me to make click event listener detailed above to work in Rails4/React?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no reactjs in this code sample.

Comment: Hy @databyss, I've update the question with react code. Let me see whether it is enough. Thanks!

Comment: I think part of the problem is that React is a different design pattern. You don't deal with html elements and dom elements in react, you deal with react components, and react handles the dom. You won't be able to interact with the dom, using jquery, as you would expect. You would instead put an onClick handler on the hamburger react component that triggers a state update, to change the display.

Comment: Something like: <button onClick={myHandlerFunction} className={'hamburger hamburger--htla'}>